# Find a linear transformation that takes a line to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Please help me to find a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ that takes the line $2x+3y=6$ to the line $2x-3y=6$. I have found an affine transformation which is $T=(0,6)+\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$ but I can not find a linear transformation.

Comment: Keep only the linear part.

Comment: But then it can not take the point $(t,2-\frac{2}{3}t)$ to the point $(t,2+\frac{2}{3}t)$.

Comment: I don't know, but I guarantee a direct calculation shows the image of the line with equation $2x+3y=6$ is the line $2x-3y=6$: just make the substitution \begin{cases} x'=x,\\y'=-y.\end{cases}

Comment: The point $(t, 2+\frac{2}{3}t)$ is not on the line $2x-3y=6$. But the point $(t, -2+\frac{2}{3}t)$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ is of the type $f(x,y)=(ax+by,cx+dy)$. Both points $(3,0)$ and $(0,2)$ belong to the line $2x+3y=6$. So, pick $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that both $f(3,0)\bigl(=(3a,3c)\bigr)$ and $f(0,2)\bigl(=(2b,2d)\bigr)$ belong to the line $2x-3y=6$. What this means is that$$6a-9c=4b-6d=6.$$